# Calculate flux Triple Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$R=\{z^2-4z+y^2 \le 0,0 \le x \le 1\}$

with $F=(x\sqrt{y^2+z^2},-z,y)$

So it's a shifted cylinder : $(z-2)^2+y^2=4$

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x&=x\\
y&=2\sin\theta\\
z&=2+2\cos\theta
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

It's a closed surface so I can use the Divergence Theorem :

$$div(F)=\sqrt{y^2+z^2}=r.$$

The flux outgoing the surface is : $\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{8+8\cos\theta}}\int_{0}^{1}r^2dx\,dr\,d\theta$

$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{8+8\cos\theta}}\int_{0}^{1}r^2dx\,dr\,d\theta$=$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{8+8\cos\theta}}r^2\,dr\,d\theta$=$\frac{1}{3}$$\int_{0}^{\pi}(8+8\cos\theta)^{\frac{3}{2}}d\theta=?$

How can I solve this ? (I tried a lot of substitution)
  Or, is there an easier setting for the integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the use of $\;\cos\theta=2\cos^2(\theta/2)-1\;$ the integral becomes 
$$I={1\over 3}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(16\cos^2(\theta/2)\right)^{3/2}\,d\theta.$$
Note that $\cos(\theta/2)\geq 0$ if $\theta\in [0,\pi].$ Thus is $\left(\cos^2(\theta/2)\right)^{3/2}=\cos^3(\theta/2),$ and we solve
$$I={1\over3}\int_{0}^{\pi}64\cos^3(\theta/2)\,d\theta={1\over3}\int_{0}^{\pi}64\big(1-\sin^2(\theta/2)\big)\cos(\theta/2)\,d\theta$$ 
Can you go from this?

Comment: Wow great combination. So I can use $cos\theta=2cos^2(\theta/2)$ only if $\theta\in [0,\pi] $?

Comment: For any $t$ is $\cos t = \cos^2 (t/2)-\sin^2(t/2)$ and $1=\cos^2 (t/2)+\sin^2(t/2).$ Summing both we get what I wrote :)